Will response from axios.get be triggered after api sends a redirect (response 302 instead)?

I have a function in React that gets an endpoint from Net Core,
then waits for a response.
This endpoint returns a redirect.
That redirect page, at the end, will call a callback function from Net Core.
Then finally Net Core is send a JSON data as response to my React.

When will the response from my original React request be filled/triggered?
When Net Core sends a Redirect or when Net Core finally sends a response to my Net Core?
